# Starting a JNLP application with an existing installation of JRE x86 and x64?

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

Our customers have partially the JRE x86 and x64 installed in parallel. The JNLP starts on Windows by default on HKEY Classes Root JNLPFile. However, this shows either the x86 or x64 path.

If it is a x86 application and the application is started with the x64 javaws controlled the x64 javaws webstart the change to the x86 path?

The attribute "arch" has no effect and the application chrashs at startup.

Answer (score 2):

Java 8u102 intoduced a [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8161986) in Java Web Start which occurs when both the 64-bit and 32-bit JRE/JDK are installed and the application needs different JARs for 32/64 bit (in our case, it was an SWT application, which needs a different swt.jar for each arch).

It seems that you can work around this bug by specifying the resources for 64-bit first in the jnlp. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="file:///c:/jnlp" href="demo.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Demo</title>  
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security> 

    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.8+"/>
        <jar href="demo.jar" />
    </resources>
    <resources os="Windows" arch="amd64">
        <jar href="win64/swt.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Windows" arch="x86">
        <jar href="win32/swt.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <application-desc main-class="package.to.MainClass"/>
</jnlp>
```

The key is that resources for `arch="amd64"` appear before resources for `arch="x86"`

If you have an application that will only work with 32-bit and should never be run with a 64-bit JRE at all, you can force javaws to use the 32-bit JRE by specifying an invalid j2se version for 64-bit (`1.0.0` in this case, note that j2se version needs to be specified inside the arch-specific resources section for it to work).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="file:///c:/jnlp" href="demo.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Demo</title>  
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security> 

    <resources>
        <jar href="demo.jar" />
    </resources>
    <resources os="Windows" arch="amd64">
        <j2se version="1.0.0"/>
    </resources>    
    <resources os="Windows" arch="x86">
        <j2se version="1.8+"/>
        <jar href="win32/swt.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <application-desc main-class="package.to.MainClass"/>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting this incident. we are working onto fix this issue - https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8161986.